# Why do avatar pictures change when I update my email address as an OAuth2 user?

Tags: support, profile-page, profile-picture, oauth2

My avatar seems to change when I update my email address if logged in using an OAuth2 provider.

Wondering why that is?

Also wondering what sort of business rules govern this decision that allow your OAuth2 verified email to be "changed on the fly"?

Currently facing a similar decision for my own website and I'm wondering whether or not to allow this sort of thing.

Pros/Cons?

Comment: Do you mean the auto generated identicon image or the image you have uploaded yourself?

Comment: @ChrisF Yes, the image I have uploaded is replaced with a generated one.

Comment: It's not supposed to change your email address upon login if you already have an email address on your profile. It's just supposed to fill it in if it was empty. Could be a bug. (Please correct me if I'm way off base about your problem.)

Comment: @animuson I'm saying after logging in with an OAuth2 provider - I can go to the *edit* tab and change my email. Was this action intended to be allowable?

Comment: @DanKanze Yes, you can change your email address to whatever you want. The email field on your profile is not at all connected to your login methods. Those can be found by clicking the "my logins" link further to the right. Your email field is only used for account recovery purposes (figuring out who you are if you contacted support), and potentially to email you if we ever sent you a moderator message.

Comment: @animuson I see. Ok so then after updating my email address after logging in with an OAuth2 provider - my avatar is regenerated.

Comment: Right, because you're set to use Gravatar, which depends on a hash of your email address in that field. If the email changes, so does the hash. You'd need to either register the alternate email with Gravatar *or* just upload your profile picture manually so it doesn't pay any attention to the email.

Comment: @animuson I see... Okay that makes sense... So I'm most curious about the logic behind the email field you set for OAuth2 providers. If my email associated with a particular provider is X, that's what's initially shown right? If I change it to Y, and then log out / log back in - you guys have logic in place to know that I'm overwriting X? I'm thinking it's something like `email = email._new?email._new:provider.email` ?

Comment: As far as I know, it only checks to see if the email is *blank* and if it is will import the email from whatever provider you just logged in with, if available. It's not supposed to overwrite an email you already have in your profile.